# AngularJS ng-repeat for bootstrap-ui tabs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angularjs and bootstrap-ui to build some tab.

I want two tabs:

Grades and Entrance exam.  My JSON looks like this (I can change this if I need to):

```
[
      {
        "name":"University of Aberdeen",
        "sections": [
          {
            "title": "Grades",
            "data" : [
              {
                "heading": "GCE - AS Levels",
                "paragraph": "Do not currently form part of academic requirement. AS module resits are permitted providing the final three A levels are undertaken simultaneously over two years of study. GCSE English and Maths needed at grade C minimum."
              },
              {
                "heading": "Re-application",
                "paragraph": "Reapplication is accepted with no disadvantage to the applicant."
              }
            ]
          },
           {
            "title": "Entrance exam",
            "data" : [
              {
                "heading": "GCE - AS Levels",
                "paragraph": "Do not currently form part of academic requirement. AS module resits are permitted providing the final three A levels are undertaken simultaneously over two years of study. GCSE English and Maths needed at grade C minimum."
              },
              {
                "heading": "Re-application",
                "paragraph": "Reapplication is accepted with no disadvantage to the applicant."
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }

]
```

What I'm trying to do is use ng-repeat and in the Grades tab you only see the first set of data and in the second tab you only see the second data array.

```
<tabset type="pills">
 <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" select="getContent()" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
      <h1>{{tab.title}}</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="item in tabs.content">
          <div ng-repeat="item in item.sections">
            <div ng-repeat="item in item.data">
              <h3>{{item.heading}}</h3>
              <p>{{item.paragraph}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </tab>
    </tabset>
```

Currently both sets of data are being pulled into both tabs. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, after looking at your Plunkr I understand your problem. Try the following:

```
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" select="getContent()" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
    <div ng-hide="!tabs.isLoaded">
      <h1>{{tab.title}}</h1>
      <div ng-repeat="item in tabs.content">
        <p>{{item.fruit[$parent.$index]}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="tabs.isLoaded"><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
  </tab>
```

This solution will display the key-value pair at `index = $parent.$index`. This will look like: `{"Apple":"Apple content goes here"}` for the apple tab and `{"Pear":"Pear content goes here"}` for the pear tab. In order to narrow it down to the value only, you'll have to say `item.fruit[$parent.$index]["Apple"]` for the apple tab to display Apple content goes here, and `item.fruit[$parent.$index]["Pear"]` for the tab pair. That's not going to help us though, so I recommend refactoring.

Maybe something more abstract? Maybe something like...

```
[
 {
   "fruits":
      [
        {
          "name": "Apple",
          "content" : "content goes here"
        },
        {
          "name": "Pear",
          "content": "pear content goes here"
        }
      ]
 }
]
```

An object that has a property called "fruits" that is an array of fruit objects. Each fruit object has name and content as keys. This way you can always use something like item.fruit[$parent.$index]["Name"] in an ng-repeat and it'll always output the corresponding name.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<tabset type="pills">
  <tab ng-repeat="section in sections"
       heading="{{section.title}}"
       select="getContent()"
       active="tab.active" 
       disabled="tab.disabled">
    <div ng-repeat="class in section.data">
      <p>{{class.heading}}</p>
      <p>{{class.paragraph}}</p>
    </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Does this give you the result you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Patrick but unfortunately not. I know it would be easier to identify if I set up a fiddle, will try do that when I get a chance.

Comment: Alright I'll try to keep an eye on this page and wait for the fiddle.

Comment: Hi Patrick, here is a Plunker to simplify this: http://plnkr.co/edit/iIJVuIxspDRedN7ZXiTK?p=preview